# Firebase: Is it possible to add a new Email/Password account when that email already is being used for a Google, Microsoft etc account?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Under sign-in method, I've already enabled "Multiple accounts per email address".

I have the same email address connected to both a Google account and a Microsoft account - so I have successfully been able to create two separate users on the same Firebase instance using the Google and Microsoft Sign-in methods.

What I'm not able to do is create yet another account for the Email/Password method. If I attempt to add it through the console (Add an Email/Password user) I get an "already exists" error, and a generic error if I attempt to add it via the admin SDK.

Can you please advise if what I'm attempting to do is possible, and if so what I should do?

Edit: I should have made it clear - the question is about allowing multiple (unlinked and entirely independent) accounts that share the same email address, rather than a single Firebase account connected to multiple providers.

Edit 2: I've marked the first response as the answer - I assume that, for security reasons, it isn't possible to simply add an email/password account when there's already an account from a trusted provider (such as google.com), so we've taken the approach to have multiple providers on a single account as outlined in the response marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, email and password credentials may be linked to existing Firebase accounts. The Firebase web documentation describes the process as follows.

> ## [Link email address and password credentials to a user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account)
>
> To add email address and password credentials to an existing user account:
>
> 1. Sign in the user using any authentication provider or method.
> 2. Prompt the user for an email address and new password.
> 3. Create an `AuthCredential` object with the email address and password:
>
> ```
> var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
> ```
>
> 4. Pass the `AuthCredential` object to the signed-in user's `linkWithCredential` method:
>
> ```
> firebase.auth().currentUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(function(usercred) {
>   var user = usercred.user;
>   console.log("Account linking success", user);
> }, function(error) {
>   console.log("Account linking error", error);
> });
> ```
>
> The call to `linkWithCredential` will fail if the credentials are already linked to another user account. In this situation, you must handle merging the accounts and associated data as appropriate for your app:
>
> ```
> // Get reference to the currently signed-in user
> var prevUser = auth.currentUser;
> // Sign in user with another account
> auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then(function(user) {
>   console.log("Sign In Success", user);
>   var currentUser = user;
>   // Merge prevUser and currentUser data stored in Firebase.
>   // Note: How you handle this is specific to your application
>   // After data is migrated delete the duplicate user
>   return user.delete().then(function() {
>     // Link the OAuth Credential to original account
>     return prevUser.linkWithCredential(credential);
>   }).then(function() {
>     // Sign in with the newly linked credential
>     return auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
>   });
> }).catch(function(error) {
>   console.log("Sign In Error", error);
> });
> ```

Comment: My apologies, I should have made this clear - the question is about allowing multiple (unlinked and entirely independent) accounts that have the same email address, rather than a single Firebase account connected to multiple providers.

Eg, when I log in with Google and Microsoft accounts that have the same email address, it creates two different accounts that are in no way linked - which is what we want. But in addition, we want to be able to add an Email account that is also independent of the Google and Microsoft accounts.